# Create dynamic Object in C# out of json

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, dynamic

i want to make a dynmamic class in C# out of a Json.
I Know i can you deserialize to convert the json but my problem is:
If i know how the json looks like (e.g. `{  "id": "5",  "name": "Example" }` i can call the value with obj.id or obj.name
BUT
i have a JSON with one property Array that could be diffrent in every instance. E.G.

```
{
  "id": "5",
  "name": "Example",
  },
  "config": {
    "Time": "13:23",
    "Days": ["Monday", "Thuesday"]
}
```

or

```
{
  "id": "5",
  "name": "Example",
  },
  "config": {
    "ServerURL": "https://example.com",
    "Category": "API"
}
```

So how i can convert this diffrent JSONs to ONE dynamic object?

Comment: EDIT: only the field "config" have different properties, the rest are always the same

Answer (score 6):

```
        dynamic o = new ExpandoObject();
        o.Time = "11:33";
        var n = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(o);

        dynamic oa = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExpandoObject>(n);
        Console.Write(oa.Time);
        Console.Read();
```

Answer (score 5):

You could do something like:

```
var jObj = JObject.Parse(jsonData);
```

And jObj becomes your 'ONE dynamic object', to access further properties:

```
var idObject= jObj["id"].ToObject<string>();
```

Or for config, you could do:

```
var configInfo = jObj["config"].ToObject<Dictionary<string, string>>();
```

PS: I had similar quesiton, you can check the question at [JSON to object C# (mapping complex API response to C# object)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46117869/4794396) and answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/46118086/4794396

**EDIT:**
You may want to map config to map your config info with something like `.ToObject<Dictionary<string, object>>()` since it could be anything..

Answer (score 0):

```
public class YourObject
{
   public string id;
   public string Example;
   public YourConfig config;
}
public class YourConfig
{
   public string Time;
   public string[] Days;
   public string ServerUrl;
   public string Category;
}
```

Json will convert your object based on property(Field name ) if your json contains example ServerURl and Category Time days will be null and vice versa.You can check based on null which json arrived

Comment: True but if i have 100 different Jsons with different Configs so i have to make 100 classes, right?

Comment: ExpandoObject In System.Dynamic namespace look at usage

Comment: look i just posted answer

Answer (score -2):

you can use this approach, this has worked perfectly for me.

```
    var vModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(JsonData, new IsDateTimeConverter { DateTimeFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy", culture = cultureInfo.InvariantCulture});
```

Comment: As mentioned by OP, there isn’t a fixed `T` yet since the structure is changing.